# Electrical wire inside Schedule M copper tubing

Tags: electrical, conduit

Is it ok to run electrical wires in schedule M copper tubing?  I have recently installed electric cove heaters in my house and I do not want to run the wires through the wall.  I am thinking about using copper tubing to hide the wires in a sort of "industrial" decorative way.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what the NEC has to say about this but just on first principles it seems that copper would be exactly what you would choose to *maximize* the dangerous effects of inductive heating via accidental eddy currents.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri -- actually, *steel* is far worse than either Cu or Al re: eddy current losses. (It's why ferrous pans work a treat on induction, where copper or aluminum pans just don't work at all in that scenario).

Comment: If you *really* want the copper color, you could get red brass RMC, but oh boy, that's going to be expensive....

Comment: @threephase I did not know that was a thing.  Does anyone stock it?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- it was used in some pool systems where GRC and EMT didn't provide enough corrosion resistance, and perhaps in other corrosive environments as well (before PVC-coated GRC was a thing).  I suspect it's special-order-only nowadays though

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not a listed wiring method. Also, the wires would never make it around the corners.

But why not just use EMT, then?  It has the same industrial look, and it's easy to work with once you get the hang of it.   Paint it copper *if you really want to*.